starfont character numbers
I'm trying to use planetary and zodiacal symbols in mathematical formulae and tikz diagrams. I found a useful code online on how to declare the characters of the starfont package as mathematical symbols:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[starfontserif]{starfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{starfontsym}{OT1}{sts}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSun}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{115}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathMercury}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{102}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathVenus}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{103}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathTerra}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{76}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathMoon}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{100}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathMars}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{104}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathJupiter}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{106}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathSaturn}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{83}


\begin{document}


\begin{align}
    & \mathSaturn : g_\mathSaturn, \quad \mathTerra : g_\mathTerra
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    &\frac{\Delta m_\mathSaturn}{m-m_\mathTerra} = \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{\Delta v_\mathSaturn}{I_{\mathrm{sp}}g_\mathTerra}} \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}

The issue I have is that although this example code is very insightful, it does not specify where the compiler got the symbol numbers from for starfont to allow us to add other characters like zodiacal signs to the list of declared symbols. The starfont documentation is also not helpful in that it does not give the codes for each character. There is a pdf table of all the available symbols in the font available with the starfont package, but the numbers don't correspond to the ones the compiler of the above code used.
Does anyone know where I can get the full list of numbers for each symbol in the starfont package from?

Please don't use ''' as code fence - it does not work

You can find all the symbol numbers used in the starfont package in https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ps-type1/starfont/starfont.sty

Thank you for letting me know. How do I then specify a code?

use ` instead.

You're amazing! Thank you so much!

the package comes with a table of all the characters in the font, and their numbers https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ps-type1/starfont/table.pdf

That was the table in the PDF that I was referring to. I just don't know how to extract the actual symbol number used in declaring the math symbol from the numbers given in that table

the numbers are given in the table headings in hex on the right and bottom and octal top and left so the symbol that looks like Asc  has 3x on the right and it's in the top half of that row so x is 1 (it would be 9 for the character below it) so the number you need is "31

The font comes with the table of characters in its documentation. But even if there wasn't you can make it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[starfontserif]{starfont}

\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{OT1}{sts}{m}{n}

\end{document}

The table this produces shows the code points in octal, hexadecimal and decimal.

If you look for 115 in the table, you find

Of course you want to first find the symbol you need and then read the number next to it that will be fed to \DeclareMathSymbol.
Alternative way that doesn't need font table lookup
You can also retrieve the number without looking up the font table, but just the symbol names in the package.
It turns out that the package does the equivalent of
\newcommand{\Sun}{{\stchar 115}}

so you just want to have an automatic translation.
Here's how.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[starfontserif]{starfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{starfontsym}{OT1}{sts}{m}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareStarSymbol}{m}
 {
  \coenraad_starsymbol:cN { math\cs_to_str:N #1 } #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \coenraad_starsymbol:NN
 {
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{\mathord}{starfontsym}{\exp_after:wN \tl_tail:n #2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coenraad_starsymbol:NN {c}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareStarSymbol{\Sun}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Mercury}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Venus}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Terra}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Moon}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Mars}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Jupiter}
\DeclareStarSymbol{\Saturn}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    & \mathSaturn : g_\mathSaturn, \quad \mathTerra : g_\mathTerra
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    &\frac{\Delta m_\mathSaturn}{m-m_\mathTerra} = \left( 1 - e^{-\frac{\Delta v_\mathSaturn}{I_{\mathrm{sp}}g_\mathTerra}} \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}



see the OP's comment under my comment where I also pointed at this table, he needs advice on how to read the layout

@DavidCarlisle Well, with fonttable the code point in decimal format is there just to be read.

ah true. maybe I need instructions on how to read this version of the font table layout:-)

Thank you! That's very helpful!
